# Convert nested dict to dataframe with multi-level column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm wondering how I can convert a multi-level nested dictionary to a data frame with a specific format as follows:

```py
d = {'far':{'boo': {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}}}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

would give

[image]

What I'd like to realise is a structure like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that? I would really appreciate some hint!

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
d = {'far':{'boo': {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}}}

df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, orient='index') for k, v in d.items()}, axis=1)

print (df)
    far      
      a  b  c
boo   1  2  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem perfectly!